# how to mapping the extjs model to the JSON spring mvc model

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, extjs

I am using extjs4 + JSON post + spring MVC. I know how to make it work in a simple case following this post:
http://equin0xe.blogspot.ca/2012/07/tutorial-to-start-using-extjs-4-and.html
But I have a very complicated form(more than 80 input) and also the elements of the form can vary depends on the category user selected.

My goal is to achieve some "auto" mapping between the extjs model and spring model(JPA). Because the manual work is quite bit of work and it won't fit the "dynamic form" requirement.
If "auto mapping" is not possible, at least some way to allow me fit my dynamic form into one model instead of create every model for each form at extjs.

Is there any good pattern or sample to do this?

Comment: Is there a way to "generalized" the various form inputs into a set of generic model objects?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But I don't know how to construct and submit the generic model objects to spring mvc in extjs. Is there any example or some open source project doing this?

Comment: There is really no magic to the Spring MVC stuff, its just a normal web request.  You can use a ModelAttribute in your controller, or submit everything as a JSON string and demarshall it.  Lots of options, and none are tied to what JavaScript framework you are using.

Comment: Thanks! I have used roo + spring mvc + GWT. The good thing about it is that it can bind the frontend model and backend model together. I think it is based on the fact that GWT was generated from the backend. But the bad thing is the generated thing is hard to read and maintain and you can't build the mockup without build everything. Extjs is opposite to GWT approach.

Comment: The easiest way to use Spring MVC, IMO, is to use JSPs with the Spring JSTL tags for the form pieces.  I don't know how Extjs4 is used, but I have used both Dojo (Roo uses this by default) and jQuery, and both integrate quite nicely with the Spring JSTL tags.  If Extjs4 has some issues with the Spring JSTLs, I would suggest creating a simple Roo project with a simple Dojo/JSP form and use Chrome or Firebug to see what is being sent on the POST.  O believe as long as your name your form fields to match your ModelAttribute's setter names it should all work fine.